# Announcing state with aria-expanded

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover, screen-readers, nvda

I made an accessible select component, following the ARIA guidelines. It is a [combobox](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-wai-aria-1.1-20171214/#combobox) and uses `aria-expanded` as prescribed to announce the state of the dropdown.
It works fine when the user first tabs into the component: screen readers announce the state (I tested VoiceOver/Safari and NVDA/Chrome). But on open, focus moves to an option and, since the combobox is not is focus, state is not announced.
I notice the same behavior on [w3.org's own example](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/combobox/aria1.1pattern/listbox-combo.html#ex3_label)
Is this expected behavior or should it be remediated? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: Can you try the following ? Instead of immediately focusing an option on expanding the combobox, delay it for a short delay (50, 100 or 200ms). Maybe this will leave enough time for the screen reader to announce expanded state before the selected option.
Tell me. IF it works, I'll post an actual answer.

Comment: Thanks @QuentinC. If I add a delay, VoiceOver starts announcing the button state and interrupts mid-sentence to read the option. I'm not too interested in a workaround, I'd like to understand whether this behavior constitutes an actual accessibility issue and whether my implementation is correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the pattern you are using this is expected behaviour from the small bit of functionality you described.

One thing to check though is that if I type an option that doesn't match, does it then switch state back to `aria-expanded="false"`?

Also if you tab out of the control after writing a *partial match* and then tab back into it does it automatically expand the list to include matches and add `aria-expanded="true"`?

If so then you have implemented it correctly as the expected behaviour is:

- first time visit combobox with nothing entered `collapsed` is spoken.
- start entering items and it selects relevant ones, no announcement of state.
- leave the combobox without completing a selection.
- re-enter the combobox, the list should appear if you have typed a valid option or part of a valid option and you should hear `expanded`.
- alternatively re-enter the combobox, the list should not appear as you have typed a string of characters that have no matches in the list, you should hear `collapsed`.

That is why then `aria-expanded` is needed on a combobox, it is for when you re-enter it so you know the state (or if the combobox is pre-populated it should auto expand then as well with `aria-expanded="true"`!).